# How to create custom “Duplicate” buttons for Adminhtml Edit Form and save custom module in Magento2.?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml

How to create custom “Duplicate” buttons for Adminhtml Edit Form save custom module in Magento2.1 and save and saveandcontinue Functionally not change.

Now duplicate button already create and onclick use setLocation but i have from submit so please any idea how to use button event in magento 2.1

```
        $this->buttonList->add(
            'duplicate',
            [
                'class' => 'save',
                'label' => __('Duplicate'),
                'onclick' => 'setLocation("' . $duplicateUrl . '")'
            ],
            12 // sort order
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution :

**=> Add this option at Construct**

```
$this->_formScripts[] =  "function duplicate(url){

     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                //var old_action = jQuery('#edit_form').attr('action');
                jQuery('#edit_form').attr('action', url);
                jQuery('#edit_form').submit();
     });  

}";

// duplicateUrl 

$duplicateUrl = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
    'modulename/controller/action',
    [
        'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'),
    ]
);

//Custom Button

$this->buttonList->add(
        'duplicate',
        [
            'class' => 'save',
            'label' => __('Duplicate'),
            'onclick' => 'duplicate("' . $duplicateUrl . '")'
        ],

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**=> Add this option at Construct**

```
 $this->_formScripts[] = " function duplicate(url){
           $('edit_form').submit($('edit_form').action+url);
        }";
```

**=> Custom Button**

```
 $this->buttonList->add(
            'duplicate',
            [
                'class' => 'save',
                'label' => __('Duplicate'),
                'onclick' =>  'duplicate("' . $duplicateUrl . '")'
            ],
            12 // sort order
        );
```